# unexplainable "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error and code behaviour

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory

I have written this very simple piece of code that takes an double array of point coordinates and adds their midpoints. When executing I keep getting `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` and sometimes `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. The only thing that makes it work is if I add an if else statement at the end which gets rid of all new arrays that are longer than `1000`. I was just trying to make some sense when I used this if else statement but now I am even more confused since none of the arrays that are being parsed are larger than `500` (and the output array is always `length * 2 - 1`). I have tried increasing the heap space as much as possible until my computer crashes and it has not changed anything. I really can't see anything wrong with my code, i've been looking at it for hours!

Thanks a bunch, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    public float[][] smooth(float a[][]){
        int length = a.length;
        float b[][] = new float[(length*2)-1][2];
        int x = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
            b[i+x] = a[i];
            x += 1;
            if (i < length-1)
                b[i+x] = midPoint(a[i], a[i+1]);
        }

//      if (b.length < 1000)
            return b;
//      else
//          return a;
    }

    public static float[] midPoint(float a[], float b[]){
        int length = a.length;
        float c[] = new float[length];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            c[i] = (a[i] + b[i])/length;

        return c;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import hwr.*;

public class DTWDist {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass2 mc2 = new MyClass2();

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("Perform dynamic time warping alignment on reference patterns");
        System.out.println("usage: input_list ref_list");
        System.out.println("output format: input_id ref_id distance");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    TimeWarping warpFun = new DynamicTimeWarping(new SquaredEuclidDistance());
    float input_pats[][][];
    float ref_pats[][][];
    PenDataReader reader = new PenDataReader(true);
    input_pats = reader.readFileList(args[0]);
    ref_pats = reader.readFileList(args[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < input_pats.length; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < ref_pats.length; ++j){

            input_pats[i] = mc2.smooth(input_pats[i]);
            ref_pats[j] = mc2.smooth(ref_pats[j]);
            input_pats[i] = mc2.centroid(input_pats[i]);
            ref_pats[j] = mc2.centroid(ref_pats[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input_pats.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ref_pats.length; ++j) {

            System.out.println(i + " " + j + "\t" + warpFun.calcDistance(input_pats[i], ref_pats[j]));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code more readably - is it indented like that in your real source code? Ultimately it's going to be hard to work out exactly what's wrong without knowing about `a.length`. (You say that they're all less than 500, but is that *definitely* correct? Have you included diagnostics to show that?)

Comment: What is the length of the array and what are your current memory / heap size settings?

Comment: @JonSkeet this method is used by the main class within a loop and the whole project is on hand-writing recognition. I can include the main class as well, but it won't really make sense unless you have the whole project which is very large. The main method is called by a shell script on a list of files that contain on-line hand-writing recognition data. these files are definitely no longer than 500 points.

Comment: @Amit heap size is currently set at 200 MBs

Comment: @spy-psycho - I have tested your code snippet with a 700 * 700 float array and it working fine. may be some other part of your code has a memory leak issue. Use some memory profiler to find the issue.

Comment: @spy-psycho - Also, a 500 * 500 * 2 sized float array would not take more than 2 MB of memory. So the issue is with the way you are using this piece of code and how frequently you are accessing this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code with relatively small array size and its working fine. So need to know the array size you are using and the heap setting you have.

Comment: my heap size is set to 200 MBs. I just ran the script on all the files individually and it seems to work, so the problem might be in a different class although the error message points this one out. I will now amend the main class where 'smooth' is called

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is modifying the size of the 'b' array after it is declared. Therefore you must be passing in an array 'a' with size greater than 500.

Put your if statement back in and put a breakpoint in to debug. I suspect things will become clear very quickly once you've done so.

Edit: From what I can see the problem is almost certainly in the code that calls the smooth method.

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right, I tested all the files individually and it worked fine so I have now posted the main method from which smooth is called